# When blowing into a coke bottle, do all ambient frequencies outside of a coke bottle exist in the bottle along with the Helmholtz resonant frequency?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

When blowing into a coke bottle, do all ambient frequencies outside of a coke bottle exist in the bottle along with the Helmholtz resonant frequency or does the bottle contain only the resonant frequency?

Answer (score 3):

In any resonant cavity, there will be many transient frequencies that only persist for a very short period due to destructive interference. Only resonant frequencies will constructively interfere (i.e. reinforce themselves) and so persist.

Comment: True, but I think the point of the question is whether a Helmholtz Chamber can support multiple frequencies, to which the answer is "yes," tho' I'm not sure about multiples at the same time/parameter set.  For example, you get the next octave on a flute by overblowing.

Comment: EDIT: I should add that I'm not an expert in this field, so if  the upper tones produced on said Coke bottle are an interaction between the resonant frequency inside the bottle and the airflow across the top,  I'll withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The coke bottle is a selective filter which only admits & re-radiates the resonant frequency of the bottle. The mass of air inside the neck rolls off the higher frequencies which hence cannot *enter* the bottle (i.e., the system is *mass-controlled* above the resonant frequency) and the compliance of the air inside the body of the bottle rolls off the lower frequencies which then cannot *leave* the bottle (i.e., the system is *compliance-controlled* below the resonant frequency), leaving only the resonant frequency bouncing around inside the bottle and radiating out the neck.